# how can I count total numbers of element in the list?

Tags: python

So basically, I have to design a program which counts the total number of vocabulary in the text file with the various options of POS_dic

example as POS_dic option of CC, CC option contains ['but', 'nor', 'or', 'and'] and once the user choose any text file, this program should count each CC element's appearance time and show the result with the format of {'but' : x, 'nor' : x, 'or' : x, 'and' : x}

```
POS_dic = {'CC': ['but', 'nor', 'or', 'and'],
        'WRB': ['how', 'why', 'when'],
        'RP': ['up']
        }

file = str(input("Which File? "))
file_data = []
file_open = open(file,"r")

for file_word in file_open:

    file_data += file_word.split()

file_data = [x.lower() for x in file_data]
print(file_data)

while True:
    pos = str(input("Which Pos? "))

    if pos == "CC":
        cc_count = 0
        cc = POS_dic["CC"]

        for CC in cc:

            cc_list = cc[cc_count]
            cc_count += 1

            if cc_count > len(cc):
                break

            cc_total = []
            cc_final = 0

            for CC_check in cc_list:

                cc_result = cc_list.count(cc_list[cc_final])
                cc_final += 1

                if cc_final > len(cc_list):
                    break

                #cc_total.append(cc_list[cc_final]+cc_result)
            print(cc_list)

    else:
        break
```

Comment: lets say there is a paragraph in the text file which contains 4 but, 3 nor, 1 or, 2 and then the program should search for this 4 vocabulary since user has chosen the POS_dic option of CC and the result that should be shown is {'but' : 4, 'nor' : 3, 'or' : 1, 'and' : 2}. I have absolutely no idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) won't give you a full list of words clear of punctuation and other non-word characters, it will just split on whitespace (e.g. for `The quick brown. Fox jumps over.The lazy dog !` you'll get `['The', 'quick', 'brown.', 'Fox', 'jumps', 'over.The', 'lazy', 'dog', '!']`). You'd have to post-process your list to remove / further split on punctuation at which point regex would become a better option, i.e.:

```
import re

filename = input('Which file? ')
with open(filename) as f:
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', f.read())
```

Alternatively, if you only have enough memory to fit the word list and not the full file contents, too, you can take a bit slower approach by iterating the file line by line:

```
import re

filename = input('Which file? ')
words = []  # an empty placeholder to fill iteratively
with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        words += re.findall(r'\w+', line)
```

No matter how you obtain the word list, since you want to ignore the case counting the words, you might want to just lowercase the file contents upfront (e.g. `words = re.findall(r'\w+', f.read().lower())` or `words += re.findall(r'\w+', line.lower())`) so that when you start counting you don't have to iterate over your list again just to lowercase it.

Once you have your word list you can devise your own counter by iterating over it and checking if the current word is in your list of interest, something like:

```
POS_dic = {'CC': ['but', 'nor', 'or', 'and'],
           'WRB': ['how', 'why', 'when'],
           'RP': ['up']
           }
pos = POS_dic.get(input('Which Pos? '))
pos_count = dict.fromkeys(pos, 0)  # lets create a counting dict from the values
for word in word_list:
    if word in pos_count:
        pos_count[word] += 1
print(pos_count)
```

But this is inefficient and kind of clunky, especially if you want to get multiple counts (as your code suggests) - you'd have to iterate over your word list each time you want to count some specific words. It's much better to just get the count of all the words once and then just pull out the counts of the words you're interested in. You can do it yourself like:

```
words_count = {}
for word in words:
    words_count[word] = words_count.get(word, 0) + 1

POS_dic = {'CC': ['but', 'nor', 'or', 'and'],
           'WRB': ['how', 'why', 'when'],
           'RP': ['up']
           }
pos = POS_dic.get(input('Which Pos? '))
pos_count = {p: words_count.get(p, 0) for p in pos}
print(pos_count)
```

But Pythons *batteries included* concept provides you facilities to do the boring work for you via the [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) so instead of you dealing with the count you can offload it:

```
import collections

words_count = collections.Counter(words)

POS_dic = {'CC': ['but', 'nor', 'or', 'and'],
           'WRB': ['how', 'why', 'when'],
           'RP': ['up']
           }
pos = POS_dic.get(input('Which Pos? '))
pos_count = {p: words_count.get(p, 0) for p in pos}  # filter the words_count
print(pos_count)
```

And then to get the total count you can just sum the values of the `pos_count`, e.g.: `sum(pos_count.values())`. So, to wrap it all up:

```
import collections
import re

POS_dic = {'CC': ['but', 'nor', 'or', 'and'],
           'WRB': ['how', 'why', 'when'],
           'RP': ['up']
           }

filename = input('Which file? ')
with open(filename) as f:
    words = re.findall(r'\w+', f.read())
words_count = collections.Counter(words)

while True:
    pos = POS_dic.get(input('Which Pos? '))
    if pos is None:  # input not in the POS_dic
        break
    pos_count = {p: words_count.get(p, 0) for p in pos}
    print(pos_count)  # individual counts as a dict
    print('Total: {}'.format(sum(pos_count.values()))  # sum of all the counts
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Everything works fine with your code but there is some problems that should be solved. first of all, this is the result of option 'CC',{'but': 0, 'nor': 0, 'or': 2, 'and': 1} hereby, I only have to show the result of 'or', 'and'. Basically, one the word that was counted should be shown at the result, so it should be like { 'or': 2, 'and': 1}. Is it possible?

Comment: @정재원 - You can use `pos_count = {p: words_count[p] for p in pos if p in words_count}` instead of the one above if you want `pos_count` to only include words that exist at least once.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand exactly what you mean, I will implement like below:

```py
from collections import Counter
POS_dic = {'CC': ['but', 'nor', 'or', 'and'],
        'WRB': ['how', 'why', 'when'],
        'RP': ['up']
        }

file = str(input("Which File? "))
file_data = []
file_open = open(file,"r")

for file_word in file_open:

    file_data += file_word.split()

file_data = [x.lower() for x in file_data]

count_word = {}
for k, v in POS_dic:
    count_word.update([(k,Counter(word for word in file_data if word in v)])

pos = str(input("Which Pos? "))

count_word.get(pos, None) # count word
```

function Counter will count items in iterable
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If this is what you are trying to implement but anyways.

```
import re

results = dict()
file_data = open('file.txt')

pos_dict = {
    'CC': {
        'but': re.compile(r'^but$|^but\s|\sbut\s|\sbut$|^But$|^But\s|\sBut\s|\sBut$|^BUT$|^BUT\s|\sBUT\s|\sBUT$'),
        'nor': re.compile(r'^nor$|^nor\s|\snor\s|\snor$|^Nor$|^Nor\s|\sNor\s|\sNor$|^NOR$|^NOR\s|\sNOR\s|\sNOR$'),
        'or': re.compile(r'^or$|^or\s|\sor\s|\sor$|^Or$|^Or\s|\sOr\s|\sOr$|^OR$|^OR\s|\sOR\s|\sOR$'),
        'and': re.compile(r'^and$|^and\s|\sand\s|\sand$|^And$|^And\s|\sAnd\s|\sAnd$|^AND$|^AND\s|\sAND\s|\sAND$')
    }
}

for row in file_data.readlines():
    for key, value in pos_dict.items():
        temp = results.get(key, dict())
        for text, pattern in value.items():
            existing_count = temp.get(text, 0)
            temp.update({text: existing_count+len(pattern.findall(row))})
        results.update({key: temp})

while True:
    pos = str(input("Which Pos? "))
    if pos not in pos_dict.keys():
        break
    print(results.get(pos, dict()))
```

you can add more key, values to the pos_dict as you want.
the pos_dict contains regular expression to match each vocabulary(lowercase, title case and uppercase)

Also to make sure we exactly match the vocabulary. there are 4 patterns for each case:
Example 
**^**BUT**$**  - starts with BUT and ends with BUT,
 
for lines which only have a single word BUT 
**^**BUT**\s**  - starts with BUT and ends with space,
for lines which starts with a BUT and then has other words 
**\s**BUT**\s**  - starts with spaces has BUT and ends with spaces,
for lines which has BUT in between other words 
**\s**BUT**$**  - starts with spaces and ends with BUT,
for lines which ends by BUT

Let me know If it helps you or you have some doubts.

Here is a reference to python regular expression.

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp

Also, this is my first time writing an answer, so just correct me if The answer can be made more clear.